# Can I integrate payment gateway in adobe AIR desktop application?

Tags: php, apache-flex, adobe, payment-gateway, payment

We are working on a desktop application, wherein we need to integrate payment gateway. The application is being developed using adobe air. We need to check the feasibility. Can somebody confirm that integrating payment gateway inside adobe AIR would not be an issue? Can we integrate payment gateway in adobe air desktop application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You certainly can, however their are pitfalls... and plenty of them.
[Integrating Paypal API in Adobe Flex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10539778/integrating-paypal-api-in-adobe-flex/10541251#10541251)